# WCF Service with abstract class as method parameter

Tags: c#, json, wcf

Here is example:

```
[ServiceKnownType("GetKnownTypes", typeof(Helper))]
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICommunicationService
{
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "/SendMessage")]
    string SendMessage(BusMessage message);
}

    [DataContract]
    [Serializable]
    public abstract class BusMessage
    {
       [DataMember(Name = "uid")]
       public string Id { get; set; }
    }
```

GetKnownTypes returns all subtypes of BusMessage.

Everything works fine if I generate client from wsdl. Class is properly casted and serialized.

Problems happen when I try to use something external for example Postman from Chrome.

I receive an exception that abstract class cannot be instantiated.

I noticed that field "__type" is added to json string while serializing from my client.

It contains message type like this: BusTextMessage#namespace.

I tried to add this manually as another field but it doesn't help. How to resolve problems like this?

Shouldn't I use abstract class/interface as parameter?

Comment: I don't know why you would want abstract classes for your DataContracts. Abstract is for advanced object oriented design, and is independent from service oriented architecture. What would be the problem in removing 'abstract'? 
My guess is WCF does some black magic and creates its own BusMessage non-abstract inherited class from yours.

Comment: When I remove abstract it will create object BusMessage, set all properties for this class and ignore another properties which should be for example in BusTextMessage, if BusTextMessage was sent

Comment: It sounds like you have other classes inheriting BusMessage. Can you post a sample of those? What would happen if you had a single, non-abstract, non-inherited DataContract class? That is the typical and simplest way to implement WCF DataContracts. If you get that to work, you can increase complexity slowly and see what breaks.

Comment: I know what is wrong. I just created BusMessageDto which contains fields of all inherited classes and after that I convert it to my inherited structure. Problem is that serializer has no information about class type

Comment: Why is that a problem? By definition serialized data doesn't have a type system. You can include serialized data types in the data itself, but a string doesn't know which class it contains.

Answer (score 0):

When you send "objects" to a WCF service, not the real object is sent, but the data is serialized and deserialized. You can see this as the client only has a stub class without any methods and underlying logic when you import the service reference.

The client/service try to create instances of concrete classes and deserialize them from the data. As you can not create an instance of an abstract class, you can not "pass" an abstract class to a method call through WCF.

In addition: The class being abstract does not really make sense, at least not in the example you're providing. As I said above, logic within data contract classes will not propagate to the client, so it's best to not have any logic (methods, complicated getters/setters)  in them at all. If you mind that, there's no reason making the class `abstract`.

Comment: Yeah I cannot send abstract class. How then WCF client which was  generated from WSDL send message for ex. BusTextMessage and later SendMessage deserialize it? As I said, it adds special field "__type" which contains namespace and class name. But it doesn't work when I send from PostMan Chrome

Comment: This problem is not related with abstract class. This problem is related with inheritance.

Comment: Well, what if you remove the `abstract` keyword? Does it work then? And what's the type of the instance you get? Is is the formerly abstract base class or the derived class? I'd say that while inheritance may be part of the problem, the real problem is using an abstract class as the base.

Comment: When I remove abstract it receive message of type BusMessage which is wrong in this case

Comment: Then you're not passing the correct data to the WCF service. By the way, marking a class both `[DataContract]` and `[Serializable]` is not necessary for WCF. `[DataContract]` is sufficient.

Comment: How to define proper BusMessage subtype in PostmanChrome? Should I add additional field? For ex. I wanna send BusTextMessage class, how to do that?